# How to make certain flex box element stick exactly at the center of the screen using Tailwind?

Tags: html, sass, tailwind-css

I am making a nav for my website using Tailwind CSS. The upper part of nav displayed as flex box with 3 items: logo, search bar and a div with some icons. My idea is that the search bar is always stick to the center of the screen, while the logo is on the left and icons are on the right side of the search bar. I cannot figure out how to make the search bar (middle item) stick at the center.

[as you can see, the search bar is a bit to the left from the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVDMQ.png)

Here is the code:

```html
<header class="bg-transparent">

  <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 mx-56 px-10 ">

    <div class="flex items-center">
      <h1 class="text-[#D4AF37] font-extrabold">Logo</h1>
    </div>

    <form class="flex items-center justify-center text-center w-[300px] rounded-full bg-[rgba(256,256,256,0.1)] ">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="pl-3"><img src="../assets/search_icon.svg"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search for something" class="w-full pl-4 py-2 bg-transparent
      rounded-full focus:outline-none">
    </form>

    <div class="flex items-center">
      <a href="#" class="cursor-pointer h-50 w-50">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>  
      <a href="#" class="cursor-pointer h-50 w-50">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>  
      <a href="#" class="cursor-pointer h-50 w-50">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter h-50 w-50"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="cursor-pointer h-50 w-50">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr class="mx-56 border-[#D4AF37] h-px">

  <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-row mx-56 py-4 px-20">
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-[#D4AF37]">
      <a class="text-dark text-base font-medium">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent">
      <a class="text-light text-base font-medium">About me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent">
      <a class="text-light text-base font-medium">Category</a>
    </div>
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent">
      <a class="text-light text-base font-medium">Blog</a>
    </div>
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent">
      <a class="text-light text-base font-medium">Gallery</a> 
    </div>  
    <div class="px-6 py-2 rounded-full bg-transparent">
      <a class="text-light text-base font-medium">Contact me</a> 
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

If there is better practices of creating nav and so on, please let me know.

I tried making body `{display: grid; place-items: center;}` but it didn't quite work. Maybe I should exclude the search bar from the flex box and just make it fixed, then I don't really know how to make the upper part look like I expect.

Comment: Hi, tried your code.... you have lot of margin ```mx-56``` onx axis .... I removed all of it and result is i got centre alignment.....

Comment: 1. Please trim down any code in your question to the minimum (for your question one container element and a handful of item elements would be suffiient).
2. `grid` is better suited, as it supports a centered column. The flexbox can't do this without further nested container elements.
3. If you really need to use flexbox you can add three nested containers: `.left` `.center` `.right` and set left and right to always have the same width. Place any items in the nested containers.